# C# Ler peso da balança Toledo Linha Prix PS 600

Tags: c#, serial, porta-serial

Olá, estou tentando obter o peso de uma balança da Toledo Modelo PS 600.
Utilizei o exemplo do link abaixo para realizar a comunicação:
[rnmioshi toledo Github](https://github.com/rnmioshi/LEITURA-TOLEDO-PESO--SAP-MU_2098C)

Até o momento eu consigo capturar a porta COM onde está conectada a balança e abrir a conexão da seguinte forma abaixo:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        serialPort1.PortName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PortaSerial"];  //"COM6";
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 4800;
        serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
        serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
        serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        serialPort1.DataBits = 7;
        serialPort1.NewLine = "vbCr";
        serialPort1.ReadTimeout = 500;
        serialPort1.WriteTimeout = 500;
    }


    private void Inicio_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.Open();
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            Inicio.Enabled = false;
            Parar.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Também está sendo feita a importação das DLLs:

```
 // Get a handle to an application window.
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    // Activate an application window.
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
```

No entanto, não estou conseguindo capturar o peso em nenhum momento, tanto por evento de dados recebidos pela porta COM, quanto forçando a leitura do peso da balança.

```
 private void CapturarPeso()
    {
        // Capturar peso
        _pesoAtual = serialPort1.ReadExisting();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_pesoAtual))
        {
            _pesoAtual = serialPort1.ReadTo("\x0D");
            _pesoAtual = _pesoAtual.Replace("\x02", "");
            _pesoAtual = _pesoAtual.Replace("00.", "0.");
            _pesoAtual = _pesoAtual.Replace(".", ",");
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
        }
    }
```

Alguém sabe me informar como resolver isto? Obrigado.

Comment: Algum erro ou simplesmente não consegue capturar o valor?

Comment: Não consigo pegar o valor, não ocorre nenhum erro.

Comment: Você já consultou a documentação ou entrou em contato com o suporte do equipamento?

Answer (score -1):

Oi, eu estava com o mesmo problema, e pelo menos comigo o erro estava no tempo de resposta para o comando `.ReadExisting();`

Tenta colocar ele dentro de um `while` ou um `for`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
{
  _pesoAtual += serialPort1.ReadExisting();
}
```